# Iptables bloquea acceso desde el mismo

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

Tengo un equipo con IP y unica principal 176.58.115.63.
Desde el propio equipo, no consigo acceder vía "ping" o "443" a mi misma IP 176.58.115.63
El mismo resultado si lo hago desde 127.0.1. (sin acceso ping ni via 443)

Esta es mi configuración:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set IPs_countries src
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set IPs_blacklist src
f2b-wordpress  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  81.61.155.22         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:6556
ACCEPT     tcp  --  81.61.155.22         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:12800
ACCEPT     tcp  --  81.61.155.22         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:12801
ACCEPT     icmp --  81.61.155.22         0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-wordpress (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

El puerto stá abierto:

```
netstat -putan | grep LISTEN | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      865/httpd
```

Comment: ¿No seran las dos primeras lineas de la regla INPUT?... tienes dos DROP ALL... diria que esas siempre van al final de la rule no al principio... para modificarlas puedes hacer un `iptables-save > tcpiprules`, luego editar ese archivo quitando los dos DROP esos de arriba, y despues un `iptables-restore < tcpiprules`

Comment: pues se habia puesto una 127.0.0.1 como denegada... gracias!!

Comment: pues no la veo en las rules que has pegado en la pregunta... supongo que no estaban todas o lo que sea... en fin, me alegro que te haya servido de algo :-)  (entiendo que has hecho lo del iptables-save y alli la has visto supongo)

Comment: el DROP, es un fichero. He buscado en el fichero y ahí casualmente habia la IP y rango problemática.

Comment: vaya, no sabia que podia ser un fichero... aunque eso de `match-set IPs_countries src` ya me parecia sospechoso, pues gracias, ya he aprendido algo nuevo :-)  saludos!

Comment: si! con "ipset". Se integra con iptables. Puedes añadir IP's y rangos.

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias, ya lo he puesto en favoritos, seguramente le daré buen uso :-)  (aunque soy fanatico de ConfigServer Firewall y dudo que puedan coexistir, seguramente se machacaran las rules unos a otros)